# Difference between server and geospatial server

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server

I have been working with Geoserver and ArcGIS Server but I am still not sure what make these geospatial server handle the spatial data transfer compared to the normal server, like apache & jetty, on which these are installed?

What is that factor that makes Geoserver and ArcServers to be spatially enabled?

Comment: Geoprocessing & Spatial Calculations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoprocessing apache/jetty only can serve up the resulting spatial process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling ArcGIS Server and GeoServer 'servers' is a misnomer / marketing technique. GeoServer, for instance, *uses* Jetty and optionally Apache, etc.

What these are, are applications - like hosted versions of GIS applications but with more emphasis on being able to store data and provide it as APIs - whether tiled images representing the data, the data in different formats, or a way to modify the data in *spatial* ways.

Comment: Exactly so how do they do that?

Comment: What value of 'how' are you asking for? How they store geodata? On the filesystem. They transfer it to and from with HTTP and process it with either a Java or C core with usually higher-level application code, like Python or JS, that makes decisions about making UI elements, upload forms, and such.

Comment: So it is all basically software which is hosted on some server and executes all the spatial information?